# MySQL - Getting number of days user spent on each status

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to extract the number of days a particular user spent on each status in a month from the MySQL database table. The data is saved in log format which makes it a bit hard to work with. For e.g. I need to calculate the number of days the user 488 spent on each status in the month of June 2022 only.

```
user_id old_status  new_status      modified_on         
488     3               10          31/05/2022 10:03    
488     10              5           01/06/2022 13:05    
488     5               16          07/06/2022 16:06    
488     16              2           09/06/2022 08:26    
488     2               6           30/06/2022 13:51    
488     6               2           07/07/2022 09:44    
488     2               6           08/08/2022 13:25    
488     6               1           15/08/2022 10:37    
488     1               11          02/09/2022 13:48    
488     11              2           03/10/2022 07:26    
488     2               10          10/10/2022 10:17    
488     10              6           25/01/2023 17:50    
488     6               1           01/02/2023 13:46
```

The output should look like this:

```
The output should look like:
user    status  Days
488     5       6
488     16      2
488     2       21
```

I tried multiple ways to join the same table with itself in order to find the solution but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get us started by showing us your best attempt

Comment: Show output for `SELECT VERSION();`. Also show desired output for shown data.

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.28

Comment: what is the date of the first status? in your example: `3` you will not know how much time has been spent on that...

Answer (score 0):

here is what I think you should do, first join the old_status field in the log table with the status table then use the DATEDIFF function to subtract modified_on(log table ) from created_at(or any other field in status that stores creation time) you can filter results using where clause to get certain users on certain dates

this query might help (i don't know the structure of your tables so if there is something wrong edit it to suit your needs)

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(log.modified_at,st.created_at) AS spent_time_on_staus 
FROM log_status AS log JOIN status AS st ON st.id=log.old_status
WHERE log.user_id=488 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM st.created_at) = 6
```

Comment: There is no separate table for status. I only have a single log table that stores the changes for all users. So basically it's one single table called "program_status_log" to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion to get you started. It will not get you all the way (since there are several status changes to and from the same status...)

```sql
SELECT 
  shfrom.userid, 
  shfrom.new_status as statusName, 
  shfrom.modified_on as fromdate,
  shto.modified_on as todate,
  DATEDIFF(shto.modified_on, shfrom.modified_on) as days_spent_in_status
FROM 
  status_history as shfrom 
  INNER JOIN status_history as shto 
  ON shfrom.userid = shto.userid and shfrom.new_status = shto.old_status 
WHERE
  shfrom.modified_on < shto.modified_on
;
```

I created a table based on your question and put in the data you provided, in mysql format:

```
create table status_history(
  userid int, 
  old_status int, 
  new_status int, 
  modified_on datetime
);

insert into status_history values
(488, 3,10, '2022-05-31 10:03'),    
(488,10, 5, '2022-06-01 13:05'),    
(488, 5,16, '2022-06-07 16:06'),    
(488,16, 2, '2022-06-09 08:26'),    
(488, 2, 6, '2022-06-30 13:51'),    
(488, 6, 2, '2022-07-07 09:44'),    
(488, 2, 6, '2022-08-08 13:25'),    
(488, 6, 1, '2022-08-15 10:37'),    
(488, 1,11, '2022-09-02 13:48'),    
(488,11, 2, '2022-10-03 07:26'),    
(488, 2,10, '2022-10-10 10:17'),    
(488,10, 6, '2023-01-25 17:50'),    
(488, 6, 1, '2023-02-01 13:46');
```

this produces this result, where the duration is the time spent:

| userid | statusName | fromdate | todate | days_spent_in_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 488 | 10 | 2022-05-31 10:03:00 | 2022-06-01 13:05:00 | 1 |
| 488 | 5 | 2022-06-01 13:05:00 | 2022-06-07 16:06:00 | 6 |
| 488 | 16 | 2022-06-07 16:06:00 | 2022-06-09 08:26:00 | 2 |
| 488 | 2 | 2022-06-09 08:26:00 | 2022-06-30 13:51:00 | 21 |
| 488 | 6 | 2022-06-30 13:51:00 | 2022-07-07 09:44:00 | 7 |
| 488 | 2 | 2022-06-09 08:26:00 | 2022-08-08 13:25:00 | 60 |
| 488 | 2 | 2022-07-07 09:44:00 | 2022-08-08 13:25:00 | 32 |
| 488 | 6 | 2022-06-30 13:51:00 | 2022-08-15 10:37:00 | 46 |
| 488 | 6 | 2022-08-08 13:25:00 | 2022-08-15 10:37:00 | 7 |
| 488 | 1 | 2022-08-15 10:37:00 | 2022-09-02 13:48:00 | 18 |
| 488 | 11 | 2022-09-02 13:48:00 | 2022-10-03 07:26:00 | 31 |
| 488 | 2 | 2022-06-09 08:26:00 | 2022-10-10 10:17:00 | 123 |
| 488 | 2 | 2022-07-07 09:44:00 | 2022-10-10 10:17:00 | 95 |
| 488 | 2 | 2022-10-03 07:26:00 | 2022-10-10 10:17:00 | 7 |
| 488 | 10 | 2022-05-31 10:03:00 | 2023-01-25 17:50:00 | 239 |
| 488 | 10 | 2022-10-10 10:17:00 | 2023-01-25 17:50:00 | 107 |
| 488 | 6 | 2022-06-30 13:51:00 | 2023-02-01 13:46:00 | 216 |
| 488 | 6 | 2022-08-08 13:25:00 | 2023-02-01 13:46:00 | 177 |
| 488 | 6 | 2023-01-25 17:50:00 | 2023-02-01 13:46:00 | 7 |

You still need to filter out the ones that are capturing an early status change with a later status change. I hope it gets you started.

Comment: The main concern here is the extraction of data for a particular month only. For e.g. I need to know how many days the user has spent in each status starting from 1st June 2022 to 30th June 2022. Both dates are inclusive.

Comment: that is NOT clear rereading the question...